# Is there a word for a queue or buffer of orders in a restaurant?

Tags: single-word-requests

In many restaurants, and I suppose other businesses as well, orders are taken from customers and put into a location from which a pool of servers can pick one up and service the order.

Is there are word other than "queue" for this waiting area of orders? "Queue" seems to indicate first-in first-out behavior. "Buffer" and "priority queue" sound too technical. And any word indicating a particular implementation of the holding area (anything involving a carousel or magnets) would be too specific.

I'm wondering whether in the service business there is a good term that describes the holding area for orders waiting for an arbitrary worker to pick them up and service them.

The word would be used in a clunky sentence like: "In a restaurant, waiters take the order and put it into a ______, then when a chef becomes available, the chef picks up one of the orders and starts cooking."

Comment: Any more they take orders and enter them into a computer.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't matter where they go. Is it a pool of orders or a queue or a .... ?

Comment: It's either 'pool' (if they are just picked at random) or 'queue' (if they are FIFO). Don't think I'd be happy with a pool - might be waiting for a long time for my dinner.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***check*** (or ***ticket***) ***holder***

> [Google Image](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22restaurant+ticket+holder%22&biw=518&bih=340&prmd=sinv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYxb6dv7nMAhXBDCwKHUN5D3wQ_AUIBygC&dpr=2)

Also, [***check*** (or ***ticket***) ***spindle***](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&q=%22restaurant%20ticket%20holder%22&ved=0ahUKEwij_7zFwLnMAhVCxRQKHbpTDboQjhwIBQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.fr%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.com%252FKegWorks-Restaurant-Check-Spindle%252Fdp%252FB0053GAJOI%26psig%3DAFQjCNHYWINGAZyneWiA5Yo_WwuR__10VQ%26ust%3D1462213562686293%26rct%3Dj&psig=AFQjCNHYWINGAZyneWiA5Yo_WwuR__10VQ&ust=1462213562686293&rct=j&cad=rjt) and [***slide check/ticket rack***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22check+spindle%22&biw=535&bih=351&prmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaz7OywrnMAhWHORQKHcCyBloQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=%22restaurant+check+rack%22&imgrc=uM79N1lAOQEkuM%3A)

> *Perhaps a can of Lone Star sits on the stainless steel prep table next to the spindle full of order tickets.*
>
> [Rare Magazine](https://issuu.com/raremagazine/docs/rare_sept_web)

Comment: A check spindle is used for checks the customers have already paid. It would be useless for orders the kitchen needs to process, because the cook would have to process the bottom ones first.

Comment: Agree with @PeterShor. Does anyone use the term "order rack"? Seems to me a "check" is the thing you receive when you need to pay; but the "order" is what goes to the cooks before filling out the order.

Comment: Regarding your quote from *Rare Magazine*, a spindle for order tickets would be useless for orders the kitchen needs to process, because the cook would have to process the bottom ones first. If you read the *Rare Magazine* article, it's clear that the spindle of order tickets is used for orders that have already been prepared by the cook, and are no longer in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try [docket](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/docket)

Or

Or [agenda](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/agenda#agenda__2)

You may hear or see it being used in fast food joints or restaurants.

Answer (score 0):

What about "[backlog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backlog)"?

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, as it describes the queue itself rather than a "thing to place orders in".

Comment: This is _very_ close to what I am looking for, though `backlog` refers more to "tasks" that an organization's workers pull from, as opposed to a poll from which servers work on "orders" made by customers. Things, I think, are allowed to stay in the backlog for a while, but in a restaurant that would never fly. Very close, though!

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to suggest this word as it highly associated with the medical *milieu*, but **triage** covers an important aspect of such an area, namely that items are inspected and possibly re-ordered.  For example, a chocolate soufflé might need 30 minutes in the oven, so takes priority over preparing spaghetti for the same order.

> [triage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/triage) 1.1
>   The process of determining the most important people or things from amongst a large number that require attention

Comment: But when people use that word I always wonder what falls into the third group -- items that are so unlikely to survive that it's not worth the effort to work on them.  It seems like the word, in this context, would at least suggest an incompetent cook.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are looking for the word "[Stack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/stack)". That's first-in-first-out.

[image: Tower Of Hanoi Stack]

Comment: First-in last-out is not the way restaurants operate.

Comment: Right, what they have mostly a FIFO queue, but with some priority based on what kinds of equipment is ready for what kinds of foods to prepare...

Comment: FIFO is also not how a stack operates.

Comment: A stack is FILO.  A queue is FIFO.

Comment: Maybe everyone should LILO until it gets figured out.